# What's a good list of browsers to test your web design with?

Tags: browser-testing

I'm trying to come up with a list of essential web browsers one should test their design on.

Here's what I usually use, but I would love to know if you would recommend others that I have missed?

- Firefox
- Safari
- Opera
- Google Chrome
- Internet Explorer 6 - 9
- Camino
- SeaMonkey

I know there are plenty more out there, so tell  me what you use!

Comment: I'd be more concerned with supporting mobile / ipad than I would SeaMonkey or Camino. And as for IE 6 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you're already testing far over the top - IE, Firefox, Chrome & Safari already corner more than 99% of the market in PC / Mac form. However, you could also consider testing against mobile devices on Android and Safari on iPhone.

Comment: I have an iPhone, so testing mobile safari isn't a problem, but what about Android? If a person (myself) doesn't have access to an Android phone, is there another way of testing?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox, IE 7+ (in some cases IE6 is a must but the majority of templates/themes out there actually now show upgrade notices to IE6 users), Chrome, Safari, and of course mobile are all crucial.

For mobile, one of the biggest issues definitely is the variety of screens/resolutions and also various browser types (i.e. Blackberry Browser, Opera Mobile, Safari Mobile, etc.)

I usually use Adobe Browser Lab for most of my test work since it allows you to test in a bunch of interfaces without needing to download all the software: https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html

The Net Catalyst tool from Adobe also will tell you the metrics and market size of each browser along with numerous other tidbits.

Comment: Thanks! Great info, and I will check out those resources.

Comment: where does one find Net Catalyst? I searched for it, but alas came up with nothing.

Comment: Sorry about the missing info. Net Catalyist is also called Net Averages and it's part of the Adobe CS Live suite.
The link is at:  https://netaverages.adobe.com/en-us/index.html